# Rust generic linspace function

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to implement a generic function linspace:

```
pub fn linspace<T> (x0: T, xend: T, n: usize) -> Vec<T>
    where
        T: Sub<Output = T>
        + Add<Output = T>
        + Div<Output = T>
        + Clone
{

    let dx = (xend - x0) / ((n - 1) as T);

    let mut x = vec![x0; n];

    for i in 1..n {
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + dx;
    }

    x
}
```

So far I have figured out that `T` must implement `Sub`, `Add`, `Div` and `Clone`, but now I am having issues with the `n as T` statement.

```
non-primitive cast: `usize` as `T`
let dx = (xend - x0) / ((n - 1) as T);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

I am aware of the num crate, but I am trying to implement this without external crates. Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: To convert from `usize` to `T`, look to the standard conversion traits like `From` (or more likely `TryFrom` since converting from `usize` to most other integer types is fallible)

Comment: Thanks, @kmdreko for the answer. I have added the `From<usize>` in the trait bound and have implemented the conversion using `T::from(n - 1)` (to avoid error handling for know as it would be required with `TryFrom`), yet now I am getting the error: `the trait 'From<usize>' is not implemented for 'f64'`. Any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're doing this as a learning exercise, I recommend that you require the bounds from the `num_traits` crate, which has traits like `Float` that would come useful here:

```
use num_traits::Float;

pub fn linspace<T: Float + TryFrom<usize>>(x0: T, xend: T, n: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    let dx = (xend - x0) / (n - 1).try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!());
    let mut x = vec![x0; n];
    for i in 1..n {
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + dx;
    }
    x
}
```

> yet now I am getting the error: the trait 'From' is not implemented for 'f64'.

It is not implemented because there are `usize` values that cannot be exactly represented as `f64`. The error is making you decide what to do with those. My code panics if such a value is encountered.

Also, I believe floating-point additions can accumulate errors, so a calculation based on multiplication might be a better idea:

```
pub fn linspace<T: Float + TryFrom<usize>>(x0: T, xend: T, n: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    let to_float = |i: usize| i.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!());
    let dx = (xend - x0) / to_float(n - 1);
    (0..n).map(|i| x0 + to_float(i) * dx).collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=430060ce41de1be4b657b39d1270b251)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to standard library traits, you will need to use `TryInto`, and deal with the fact that the conversion requested could fail because the number type could be smaller than the inputs. Also, unfortunately, there isn't even any fallible `TryInto<f32>` for numbers that don't necessarily fit in `f32` (or `f64`). So, we have to make the number of items `u16` which can be converted to any float type.

```rust
use core::ops::Add;
use core::ops::Div;
use core::ops::Sub;
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub fn linspace<T>(x0: T, xend: T, n: u16) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: Sub<Output = T> + Add<Output = T> + Div<Output = T> + Clone + Debug,
    u16: TryInto<T> + TryInto<usize>,
    <u16 as TryInto<T>>::Error: Debug,
{
    let segments: T = (n - 1)
        .try_into()
        .expect("requested number of elements did not fit into T");
    let n_size: usize = n.try_into()
        .expect("requested number of elements exceeds usize");
        
    let dx = (xend - x0.clone()) / segments;

    let mut x = vec![x0; n_size];

    for i in 1..n_size {
        x[i] = x[i - 1].clone() + dx.clone();
    }

    x
}
```

It will panic if given a too-large `n`, for example if `T` is `u8` and `n` is `1000`.

(By the way, repeatedly adding `dx` is not usually the best way to do this, because it can accumulate error if `T` is a floating-point type; the last element will not necessarily be equal to `xend`.)

Comment: Thank you @Kevin, I have tried your implementation in [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b0195398ed0f4ccb307a8515e5312cb0) but it is not compiling. What am I missing?
(by the way, thanks for the aside note, it was very useful!).

Comment: @SergioCavaleiroCosta Oops, I missed that there is no `TryInto<f64> for usize`. I have posted a fixed, but more limited version. Perhaps `num_traits` really is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is neater:

```
use num_traits::Float;

fn linspace<T: Float + std::convert::From<u16>>(l: T, h: T, n: usize) -> 
    Vec<T> {
    let size: T = (n as u16 - 1).try_into()
        .expect("too many elements: max is 2^16");
    let dx = (h - l) / size;

    (1..=n).scan(-dx, |a, _| { *a = *a + dx; Some(*a) }).collect()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).