# Generic function for multiplying by a constant number

Tags: generics, rust, types

I am trying to understand generic functions. I know this topic has been discussed extensively, but I can't seem to wrap my head around some details.

I am attempting something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838484), but even simpler. I just want a `double` function that multiplies the argument by two and I want it to work for any float or integer type. So far I have this:

```rust
use std::convert::From;
use std::ops::Mul;

fn double<A>(x: A) -> A
where A: Mul<Output = A> + From<f32> {
    return x * A::from(2f32);
}
```

This works fine, when I call it with a float (`f32` or `f64`):

```rust
println!("{:?}", double(2f64));
```

This gives me `4.0`.

But it fails for any integer type, for example:

```rust
println!("{:?}", double(2i32));
```

This gives the following error:

```
println!("{:?}", double(2i32));
                 ------ ^^^^ the trait `From<f32>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

I understand the error. There is no general way to cast a float to an integer. It's ambiguous how that is supposed to work, if I wanted to cast `2.5` inside my function instead of `2.0`.

I know there is the `TryFrom` trait, but I cannot figure out, how to make use of it in this situation.

---

I tried it the other way around, i.e. requiring `A` to implement `From<u32>` for example, but this just switches the error from occurring with integers to occur with floats. But what surprised me is that it also leads to an error when I call the function with a *signed* integer like `2i32`.

What am I missing? How can I realize a generic `double` function over any number type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just need to convert the number `2` to whatever type, you can convert from the smallest possible type, i.e. `From<u8>`:

```
use std::ops::Mul;

fn double<A>(x: A) -> A
where
    A: Mul<Output = A> + From<u8>,
{
    return x * A::from(2);
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", double(1));
    println!("{}", double(1f32));
    println!("{}", double(1f64));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1cef98646676dd5f6beed8f3b32590ee)

The only downside of this simple approach is that `double(1i8)` will fail to compile (but it will work with `i16`, `i32`, etc.). `From<u8>` is not implemented for `i8` because there are `u8` values that cannot be represented as `i8`. However, we know we *really* don't need to represent all `u8` values as `A`, but just 2u8. That's why we want to use `TryFrom`:

```
fn double<A>(x: A) -> A
where
    A: Mul<Output = A> + TryFrom<u8>,
{
    x * A::try_from(2).unwrap_or_else(|_| unreachable!())
}
```

The unwrap will never panic for numeric types because there is no numeric type that cannot represent the number 2.

In this case you don't need to worry about unwrapping making the code slower because rustc/LLVM understand that e.g. `f64::try_from(2u8)` is infallible and omit the panic, [as seen on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/393hf5Weq). The only downside is possible confusion for the human reader, which is why it's a good idea to use `unreachable!()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense. I know this is a separate question, but just as an aside: Why can't we just use `.unwrap()` on the `Result` returned by `try_from`? If I try that, the compiler tells me that the error can't be formatted.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Because `unwrap()` tries to provide a nice error message, which requires `Display`. You could also fix that by adding `<A as TryFrom<u8>>::Error: std::fmt::Debug` trait bound, but that doesn't make sense since the unwrap can't happen, which the code generator [can prove](https://godbolt.org/z/393hf5Weq).

Answer (score 1):

`From<f32>` means that *any* `f32` value can be converted to the target type without loss. This obviously can't be done for `i32` since all non-integer values would lose their fractional part in the conversion.

Conversely, `From<u32>` can't be done for `f32` because `f32` only have 24 bits of mantissa, so any value greater than `2^24` would loose precision in the conversion. `From<u32>` also can't be done for `i32` since values greater than `2^31` can't be represented.

Since the only value you're interested in converting is `2`, you can use `From<i8>` or `From<u8>`, but note that it will still fail for the other one:

```
use std::ops::Mul;

fn double<A>(x: A) -> A
where A: Mul<Output = A> + From<i8> {
    return x * A::from(2);
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", double(1));
    println!("{}", double(1f32));
    println!("{}", double(1f64));
    // println!("{}", double(1u8));    // Doesn't work
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4644300d3f230f95d4a0a8c7d91ac00a)

Comment: +1 For the additional explanation about the the loss of precision, if we were to try and cast `u32` to `f32`. I should have seen that.